# What's the equivalent IAM role for https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write scope

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I am converting the old way to creating GCP node pools (via --scope parameter to specific permission) to use an GCP IAM service account.

What's the proper (minimum required) predefined role that I should assign to the newly created GCP IAM service account in order to port

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write`

scoped permissions over?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#primitive-roles), the minimum role required is `roles/editor`.

> roles/editor -->
>   All viewer permissions, plus permissions for actions that modify state, such as changing existing resources.

Comment: Thanks @adrian-nieto-macias ! I am not looking for a minimum role required though. I am asking the specifics about https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write scope and what the equivalent IAM role for it.

Comment: My apologies @devy, then the roles what you need are these ones: `Storage Object Viewer and Storage Object Creator`. More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles).